# How to connect to elementary OS using rdp client (remmina)?

Tags: gala, settings, rdp

I am going to rebuild my box at work. I want to use elementary. I currently am using Ubuntu LTS and I know that it is a PITA to configure for that (need to use a different desktop). Is it possible to connect using RDP protocol (with remmina) to this desktop environment?

I do NOT want to use VNC (or its ilk), basically because I don't like it, and I do not want to be running the service, and because I use RDP (or ssh) to connect to every other server that I need to get to for my job.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to a Linux machine using a RDP client if you install the `xrdp` package.

However, what the `xrdp` really do is to translate the RDP to a VNC server, installed via package dependency. So if you don't want a VNC service running in your machine, is better to connect using SSH.

Besides that, there's a issue with the `xrdp` and "complex" desktop environments, like Gnome-shell. I don't know yet if it works fine with Gala (elementary's DE), but I'll test and edit this answer (I got curious about that).

To use SSH to connect, install the OpenSSH server:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

EDIT: Yup. No Gala via RDP. Just check it.

Comment: the issue is i use rdp to connect from home ... then from THERE ... i can have MANY ssh sessions going at one time ... i guess it would be possible with GNU screen ... but I do need X as well ... so not really sure it that is a workable solution ... PLUS from my linux workstation ... i connect to either my work virtualized windows workstation or customers windows or linux (via rdp or ssh via vpnc or openconnect and then attach to THEIR servers ... would be a real PITA any other way other than a full DE

Comment: Damn ... thanks for checking ... wasn't sure if it was just me that couldn't get it to work.

Comment: i just checked again and rdp still not working with latest version of elementaryos. it connects, move mouse and then disconnects.